# Pandas Dataframe relative indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I would like an easy way to access indices relative to a given index in a Pandas `DataFrame`. Please see the code below where a draw an analogy to a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# let's make a simple 2d matrix like array
na_a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
print na_a
print na_a[1][2]
print na_a[1+1][2] # here I want to print the next value in the same column so I iterate the row by 1

# now let's put this array into a pandas dataframe
df_a = pd.DataFrame(na_a,index = ['1','2','3','4'], columns = ['A','B','C','D'])
print df_a
print df_a['C']['2']
# now how do I easily iterate the row by 1 to print the next value in the same column?
```

Here is the output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]
7
11
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2   3   4
2   5   6   7   8
3   9  10  11  12
4  13  14  15  16
7
```

This should be possible for general relative indexing (not just +1 in one direction).

Comment: One idea behind Pandas is to be able to easily perform bulk operations to data and avoid the need to iterate.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: Why don't you just use integer based indexing, i.e. `iloc[2, 2]`?

Comment: At the highest level this is a noughts and crosses game (5 in a row). I've decided to hold the board in a DataFrame (mostly because I'm new to python). My ai opponent can now find potential threats by looking for chains of consecutive X's. Say a chain of three X's is at F5, F6, F7. My convention gives the address of the chain as F7 and it's length as 3. If the AI wants to put a O down to block the chain it must go to the address F7 and iterate the numeric index by 1 to get to F8.

Comment: Happy to hear it if I'm doing this a silly way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want to identify a new `index` label relative to another `index` label to select a new `row`.

`pandas` provides the `pd.Index.get_loc()` method to retrieve the zero-based `integer` `index` position of a label. Once you have the `integer` position, you can get the label for any offset and select a new row accordingly:

Starting at `index` `label` `'2'` for value `7` in `column C`:

```
start_index_label = '2'
df['C'][start_index_label]

7
```

The integer-based `index` corresponding to the `row` label `'2'` is `1`:

```
start_index_position = df.index.get_loc(start_index_label)

1
```

Adding `2` to get to integer-based `index` position `3` yields `label` `4`:

```
next_relative_index_position = +2
next_index = df.index[start_index_position + next_relative_index_position]

4
```

with corresponding `row` value `15`:

```
df['C'][next_index]

15
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if my label's are not integers? Maybe I'm missing the point of what a DataFrame is supposed to do for me. What if I have a DataFrame where the indexing is in calendar dates and I want to access everything between July 23 1991 and one hundred days after that (without having to know what date is 100 days later)?

Comment: I've used `string` labels to illustrate how you can go back and forth between `label` and `index` based selection; you can use `datetime` just as well. However, your question was about a specific example. For the game example you then introduced, you may be best off just using `integer`-based indexing behind the scenes, translating the field names accordingly to facilitate the arithmetic. Also please take a look at the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html